# Format image inside of li

Tags: html, css

My output from my CMS is putting my image inside of my `<li>` so everything is showing on the same line. The output looks like so:

```
    <li class="data_li">
       <a href="http://mywebsite.php">Buffalo</a> 
      <img width="363" height="136" src="http://mywebsite.php/images/BWR.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="Buffalo" title="BWR" />
      <div class="teaser_text"></div>
   </li>
```

I would like to style the output so the elements are block (fall under each other)

Any ideas of how I would accomplish this?

Comment: so the ?elements? are block (fall under each other)

Comment: Elements = Link text, the image, and div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you could do

```
.data_li img {
    display: block;
}
```

Or

```
.data_li * {
    display: block;
}
```

depending on what you want. `.data_li *` should affect every child element, so anything within `<li class="data_li">` should have a `display: block;` Obviously `.data_li img` will only affect the `img` elements within that div, like your title asked for.

Comment: Great using the wild card worked. And since I need all of the elements to display block I will use that. Thanks.